# Find direct flights to specific airport for specific date (from any departure airport)

Tags: air-travel, planning, online-resources

I try to minimise my flying, and have done all my travel without flying for the past couple of years, in order to minimise my environmental impact. I've decided to allow myself a holiday by flight next Christmas, but to still minimise environmental impact, I want to limit the flying to one leg (one leg down, one leg back). I will travel overland to and from the airports (even if this takes 1–2 days). Therefore, I'm looking for a flight search engine that will give me a reliable answer as to direct flights to a particular airport for a particular date. Where can I find such a search engine?

Case in question: flights to either Santa Cruz de La Palma or Tenerife, Canary Islands, Spain on Friday 21 December. Googling gave me http://www.flyhere.com but I know the answer is incorrect, because I know both Berlin-Tegel and Amsterdam-Schiphol have direct flights to this airport on 2012-12-21, however neither are listed there. Either I travel a short distance by train and fly directly from Scandinavia to Tenerife and take a ferry from there, or I travel further south by train and fly directly to La Palma (probably from Germany).

So: where can I find a flight timetable for direct-flight arrivals at a particular airport at a particular date?

Comment: So where do you want to start? Berlin or Amsterdam?

Comment: I will travel by train from northern Sweden to wherever I will start. I will either fly directly from Scandinavia to Tenerife and take a boat from there, or take the train further south and fly directly then. I'll clarify the question to reflect this.

Comment: So basically your searching for a non-stop flight from Southern Sweden to Tenerifa or Santa-Cruz de La Palma?

Comment: Probably Sweden or Germany, but a complete overview would be interesting, because there might be surprising possibilities (according to [flightmapper.net](http://www.flightmapper.net) there are e.g. flights Trondheim–Gran Canaria, but this site won't let me search for a specific date and I haven't explored travel to/from connecting airports yet).

Comment: I provided kind of an answer. It is not really a timetable, but a matrix flight search. There you can specify multiple airports both for departure and destination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't know where to find a flights schedule, but for questions like this a flight matrix is also a good option.

For example on http://matrix.itasoftware.com, you can select multiple departures, for example in your case, all airports in Southern Sweden and also multiple possible destinations, such as Tenerife and Santa Cruz de la Palma. Then you can also limit the number of stops, the exact date of travel, etc. Using this search engine I was able to find at least the non-stop flight from Berlin to Santa Cruz. As an additional benefit, this search engine also caluclates your CO2 footprint.

Here you can see a screenshot:

[image]

As you can see, there are direct flights from Hamburg, Berlin, Nuremburg, Frankfurt, etc.

Comment: Perfect tool, cool! I found a flight from Tromsø to Gran Canaria, much closer and cheaper than any other alternative :)

Answer (score 5):

Bear in mind that aggregators won't necessarily carry all providers or all flights.  So the best way to get a definitive answer is to do the following:

- First, assuming the destination airport is a reasonably well-known one, try Wikipedia to get a list of airlines and their destinations from that airport.  E.g. [Tenerife North](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife_North_Airport#Airlines_and_destinations), [Tenerife South](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tenerife_South_Airport#Airlines_and_destinations), [Santa Cruz de La Palma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Palma_Airport#Airlines_and_destinations).  Often the airport's website also has this information, or at least a list of airlines servicing it.
- Cross-reference those with where you want to travel from.  In this case, Tenerife South shows a number of Scandavian flights with [Norwegian Air Shuttle](http://www.norwegian.com/en/).
- Use that airline's website to determine whether it meets your requirements.

It's not quite as nice as RoflcoptrException's answer (and I'd probably recommend using that myself as an initial step), but for a definitive answer for a general case this works well.

Comment: That's more or less what I've been doing so far. Maybe a hybrid solution is good, as I didn't consider before using RoflCoptrException's link that there may be an airport even closer to me with a direct flight to another of the Canary Islands (Gran Canaria). At least the list of /airports/ is likely quite complete at such websites.

Answer (score -2):

As per your question in terms of calculating and analyzing your flights I recommend using [flightmapper.io](https://flightmapper.io/). This tool is quite handy in analyzing your routes and mapping your flight which help in setting a limit for your travels annually

Comment: Are you affiliated?  In their blurb, I don't see how they help people trying to minimise flying.  A feature "you are living a factor 12 above your means" after two transatlantic flights per year would be interesting.