# Planning flights - broad connection flights search engine?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources, flight-search-engines

Is there any tool / online search engine where you can give it a list of possible departing airports, and a list of possible arriving airports, and shows you all the possible flights (connecting or seperate) and/or airlines that operate between cities,  that can take you there?

For example, I would give it:

### Departing

- Malta

### Arriving

- Sofia
- Varna
- Bourgas

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes. This [Matrix search engine](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) does exactly what you're asking for. See also [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/8482/2509).

A screenshot showing flights from Malta to either of the three airports, departing 15 February 2013, returning 22 February 2013:

[image: matrix airfare search engine]

Comment: One word - Perfect! :)

Comment: GREAT STUFF! Indeed!