# Websites with flights TO a destination (from wherever)?

Tags: air-travel, online-resources

I know there are many sites which will allow me to find a flight to wherever from a given airport, but I haven't found one that would allow me to specify a destination and no starting location. Are there any? (Obviously, I'm looking for cheaper flights)

Comment: Concretely, I'd like to go to Bergen so any specific advice is also welcome!

Comment: skyscanner! Actually in their form the departure airport is mandatory but you can still have a precise idea of prices by choosing "fly from Bergen". You might check this question: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2615/where-can-i-find-and-book-plane-tickets-on-date-not-on-destination

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find direct flights to specific airport for specific date (from any departure airport)](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8482/find-direct-flights-to-specific-airport-for-specific-date-from-any-departure-ai)

Answer (score 2):

If you could yourself limit to an airport and all airports within a 2000 miles radius, then [Google's Matrix Airfare Search](http://matrix.itasoftware.com/) could be an option for you. Generally, all matrix flight search engines could be interesting. I did your specific search query for you and checked all the flights from Berlin, including all other airports within 2000 miles radius, to Bergen for January 2013:

[image]

If you select one of these dates, you can see the specific flights. For example for the cheap flight at January, 13., you get a list like this:

[image]

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but he asked to search with the FROM blank, and the TO set to Bergen.  Isn't this doing the reverse?

Comment: The from is not blank, but I added all airports in Europe. I don't now a search engine that allows that, so I used an approximation.

Comment: I think the only answer to this question would be this one, because there HAS to be some criteria to limit a search. Because if you think about it, any search structured as FROM anywhere to a SPECIFIC place will always be true and have options running into thousands. I also cannot imagine it to be a very useful search option: it doesn't make sense to have a flight starting anywhere in the globe, and the use case for this is weak.

Comment: Thanks, this will be more than good enough for my purposes! @AnkurBanerjee If you limit the flight to one or two stops only, it makes perfect sense: I really, really want to go somewhere and I don't care from where. My particular use-case is slightly more unique, but I was still sure there's a way to get this data (as it must exist already) and I'm glad Roflcoptr proved me true.